# Archive page no content to display

Tags: archives

I have an archive page and everything is working perfectly fine, except when someone enters a search query that returns no content (no posts were found) then I get the nothing found message.

My question is how can I target only when the search query returns nothing and have a custom template to be shown.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Without posting any code, there is not very much we can do about it. Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: @user3135691Sorry for the late reply, I'm using a page builder (elementor) I didn't write any code so far but if the solution is writing code then I don't mind